# XDocument To Read MetaBase.xml

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml, vb.net-2010

For some reason I am having a massive brain fart this morning.

I cannot get anything back from the following code... it always pops 0, and the _Qry is never populated, even though _MBXml is populated properly (hovering during debug shows it)

```
_MetaBasePath += "IIS6-MetaBase.xml" '"metabase.xml"
_MBXml = XDocument.Load(_MetaBasePath, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)
_Qry = (From n In _MBXml.<IIsWebServer>
       Select New Typing.MetaBase() With {
           .Binding = Common.IsNull(Of String)(n.@ServerBindings, String.Empty)
       }).ToList()
MsgBox(_Qry.Count)
```

Here's an example of the IIS 6 metaBase.xml file...

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:microsoft-catalog:XML_Metabase_V64_0">
<IIsWebServer   Location ="/LM/W3SVC/1174460368"
    AuthFlags="0"
    SSLCertHash="8251cc2a9671150ac107aee3d78006b032f9bc36"
    SSLStoreName="MY"
    SecureBindings="184.106.185.111:443:"
    ServerAutoStart="TRUE"
    ServerBindings="184.106.185.111:80:beta.turbokits.com"
    ServerComment="TurboKits Beta"
>
</IIsWebServer>
</configurarion>
```

Comment: also tried this with ...<IIsWebServer> and .Elements("IIsWebServer")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the metabase.xml has a default namespace declaration (i.e. `xmlns="http://example.com/"`) then make sure your VB code has

```
Imports <xmlns="http://example.com">
```

in the Imports section. Of course you need to make sure you adapt `http://example.com/` to the actual URL used in the XML document.

If you still have problems then show us a sample of the XML.

Comment: Actually...  that looks like it may have done the trick:  'code' Imports <xmlns="urn:microsoft-catalog:XML_Metabase_V64_0">

Comment: Yes, the default namespace declaration in the XML input applies to the root element and its descendant elements and with VB.NET to handle that the `Imports` is the right approach. As an alternative if you don't want to rely on the VB.NET compiler you could do `Dim df As XNamespace = _MBXml.Root.Name.Namespace` and then use the query methods `Elements` or `Descendants` with e.g. `_MBXml.Elements(df + "IIsWebServer")`.